# command not waiting for Answer

Tags: command-line, powershell

In this script,

```
@echo off
echo copie du script PowerShell vers le dossier temporaire de Windows
copy "\\ftp-stg1\FTP Root\Programs\script\vmprog.ps1" C:\Windows\Temp
echo copie du script CMD vers le dossier temporaire de Windows
copy "\\ftp-stg1\FTP Root\Programs\script\package_install.cmd" C:\Windows\Temp
echo ouverture du RDP
powershell -command "Set-ItemProperty -Path 'HKLM:\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Terminal Server' -name "fDenyTSConnections" -value 0"
echo installation de boxstarter
powershell -command "Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Force"
powershell -command ". { iwr -useb https://boxstarter.org/bootstrapper.ps1 } | iex; get-boxstarter -Force"
C:\Windows\Temp\package_install.cmd
exit
```

After the command `. { iwr -useb https://boxstarter.org/bootstrapper.ps1 }` the command window closes but I have another command wating for action.

What do you suggest?

Comment: You could add a `pause` to keep the window open to see if there's any output before it closes ? (and to see if it even gets as far as that statement, or closes for another reason)

Comment: I did. this is the result...
https://images2.imgbox.com/5a/b8/60pA0xVx_o.png

Comment: I Think I'm fighting a lost cause...

Answer (score 0):

it should work if you change this line:

```
powershell -command ". { iwr -useb https://boxstarter.org/bootstrapper.ps1 } | iex; get-boxstarter -Force"
```

to this:

```
Start-Process PowerShell -Argumentlist "iwr -useb https://boxstarter.org/bootstrapper.ps1 | iex; get-boxstarter -Force" -Wait
```

by using the `-Wait` Parameter of `Start-Process` you tell PowerShell to halt the execution of the script until the process closes